# Time Series analysis with R - multiple input variables besides time period

Tags: r, time-series

I thought the problem I am having should be common, but for some reason I cannot really find good answer so far, so here is my problem - I am doing time series analysis using R, and my data looks like

```
time_period customer# sales_amt    sales_qty
2013/01      123      $xxx,xxx.xx   xxx
2013/01      345      $yyy,yyy.yy   yyy
2013/02 ....
```

so far, I can do it for each customer manually one by one, but when I have more than 100 customers, it is not possible to do it this way, I would like to be able to do it in just one go to include all customers, also, later on I will have to include other input variables as well, like sales region besides customer#, how should I include those additional input variables?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not an answer since you don't ask a precise question. It is a recommandation or HOW O would do this.

First You should create a data.frame with all your variables. 
Then To process your data by group , one option is to use `ddply` from `plyr` to use `split-apply-bind` paradigm. for example, assuming `dat` is your data.frame.

```
## process by customer
ddply(dat,.(customer),
      function(x){ 
         ## here you procces each time customer time series
            xts(x$sales_amt,x$time_period)
       })
## by customer and by region
ddply(dat,.(customer,region),
      function(x){ 
         ## here you procces each time customer time series
            xts(cbind(x$sales_amt,x$sales_qty),x$time_period)
       })
```

Note that I am using `xts` package to deal with time series object.